# Android, changing orientation of WebView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have fragment with webview and I need to play video in fullscreen. I can't use android:configChanges="orientation|screensize" in AndroidManifest to MainActivity, because MainActivity has two different layout for lanscape and portrait mode. Calling the method setRetainInstance on a fragment does retain the fragment (it does not get destroyed), hence all the instance variables of the fragment are preserved, however it does destroy the fragment's view hence the WebView does gets destroyed.

Comment: @d0pestar, have you found solution for your problem?